# Setting of Textbox.TextAlignment in code-behind of WPF produces wrong results

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm programming a WPF-app with VS 2015.
In my code i'm setting properties of FrameworkElements/controls like that:

```
if (textblock.GetType().GetProperty("TextAlignment") != null)
    textblock.GetType().GetProperty("TextAlignment").SetValue(textblock, value);
```

The variable textBlock of type FrameworkElement contains in this case a TextBlock control.
When i set per example value = HorizontalAlignment.Center and check the property after it, it contains "HorizontalAlignment.Right".

Why does this happen and what can i do to prevent it?

Thanks in advance,
Patrick

Answer (score 0):

I have found it out!
The TextAlignment property has it's own TextAlignment enumeration.
When i tried to set HorizontalAlignment.Center the result was TextAlignment=Right.
But with Textalignment=TextAlignment.Center the result is correct.